# Extreme lag when using Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

Can anybody help to resolve LAG?

Ubuntu 22.04. Windowing X11. Nvidia gtx 1050 ti. AMD 6core. Ram 32gb. Libreoffice 7.3.3.2 installed from repository.

Having some major issues with LO 7.3.

- no fonts show in dropdowns (solved by switching to X11)
- no offline help (solved by installing a new browser, slimjet)
- cannot access files anywhere other than /home
- sever lag during data input and scrolling

The worst is the LAG. About 1 second in Writer, many seconds in Calc, cannot scroll large files.

In prior years, I solved this by deleting libreoffice-gtk3 and replacing with libroffice-gtk2. But for Ubuntu 22.04, -gtk2 is gone.

In the LO forum, someone commented the problem is not LO, but stems from the distro packager.

I have tried the LO 7.3 Snap and TDF releases. No improvements.

btw, command 'free-h' returns the following...

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi       2.7Gi        25Gi       421Mi       2.6Gi        27Gi
Swap:          979Mi          0B       979Mi
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `libreoffice` from the terminal, and look for error messages

Comment: Also, libreoffice-gtk2 seems to be available for jammy. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libreoffice-gtk2

Comment: @ Archisman... libreoffice from terminal... launches without errors.  Correct: -gtk2 is unavailable for Jammy.

Answer (score -1):

Solved...by deleting Ubuntu...replaced with Pop!_OS.

Comment: You know that Pop!_OS is essentially Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. But Ubuntu 22.04 is full of bugs and problems. The lads at Pop have resolved them all to make Pop work perfectly.